# Laravel 5.6 - How to get post data from non-relation table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6. Below of my table

Table: categories

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | name      |  slug    |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Cat1      | cat1     |
|  2 | Cat2      | cat2     |
|  3 | Cat3      | cat3     |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Table: posts

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id  | name       |  photo   |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | Post1      | img1.jpg |
|  2 | 2        | Post2      | img2.jpg |
|  3 | 1        | Post3      | img3.jpg |
|  4 | 1        | Post4      | img4.jpg |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
```

Table: post_categories

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| id | post_id  | category_id  |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 | 1        | 1            |
|  2 | 1        | 2            |
|  3 | 1        | 3            |
|  4 | 2        | 1            |
|  5 | 2        | 3            |
|  6 | 3        | 3            |
|  7 | 4        | 2            |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

Above I have posted my 3 table. Here is `post_categories` table relation with `posts` and `categories` table. I want to show all post categories wise. Below see my output looks like:

```
Cat1
   Post1
   Post2
Cat2
   Post1
   Post4
Cat3
   Post1
   Post2
   Post3
```

URLs:

> > http://chhayalsing.com/blog
> >
> > http://chhayalsing.com/blog/category/people

*N.B:* If you are facing to read our local language. Could you please change language `Odia` to `English` (Change Language option exist in the footer section)

`People` category having 8 posts. But here is showing all. I don't have any idea about this query. I tried:

```
$posts = Post::with([
    'user' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'username']);
    }, 
    'comments', 
    'post_category' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'name']);
    }
])->where('status', '=', 1)
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($perPage);
```

I know my code was wrong. But I am totally new on this framework. Unable to do that. Could you please provide me query with pagination for getting post list.

Comment: If you setup the relations correctly, you can do something like this: `$posts = Post::with('category')->get();` This will return all posts where category matches. Take a look at [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily query to get all of category `$cats = Cat::all()`. Then, using a loop to get all post of each category `$cat` and push it into your child of `$cats`.

Finally, you will have only one element (may be `$cats`) . It would be look like that:

`$cat = {
  items: array:2[
    1 => {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "cat1:,
      "post": array:3 [
         1 => post1 detail,
         2 => post2 detail,
         3 => post3 detail
        ]
    },
    2 => {
       "id": "2",
       "name": "cat2:,
       "post": array:2 [
        1 => post1 detail,
        2 => post2 detail,
       ]
    }
}`

Then, in blade, use only $cats could help you to pass all data about $cat and $post of ifself.